# Saying or expression for "behave or f... off"

Tags: phrase-requests

I remember reading a saying or expression that was used to warn someone to behave. It was along the line of (teaser because it contains an offensive word):

> Stay and behave here or fuck off

If I recall correctly, it was mostly used in jobs or businesses to tell employees to either behave or leave. An example would be:

An employee is acting up so the boss tells him or rather gives him a warning and says "behave or f... off" (it didn't have the word "f..." but I feel that both have more or less similar meanings of dismissing someone).

I've been scratching my head for that expression but can't seem to find it.

Comment: Are you asking about British or American English?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You're probably looking for **‘shape up or ship out’**.

From [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/shape_up_or_ship_out):

> Used as an ultimatum to someone to improve their performance or behaviour or face being made to leave.

Comment: More coarsely, and normally when addressee is failing to perform some *specific* action: [*Shit or get off the pot*.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22shit+or+get+off+the+pot%22) Plus the boss might tell a "non-compliant" employee to *[Do things] **my way or** [take to the] **the highway*** (where the second option means ***leave / be sacked***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I use “shape up or ship out” and “shit or get off the pot” very differently.  The says “mend your ways or leave- we won’t tolerate your misbehavior”  the latter means “quit *talking* about what you’re going to do and do it or get out of the way so someone else can.”

Comment: @Jim is right. 'Shit or get off the pot' is an unrelated idiom to this question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "Shit or get off the pot" is not "behave or leave". It's "stop talking and act or shut up". "My Way or the Highway" is a good alternative though but not sure it's quite right.

Comment: "My way or the highway" generally means that you have to conform to the established standard even if your way is not inferior.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was after.

Comment: @Jim, Alex: I think you're both unreasonably limiting the potential scope of "shit or get off the pot". Just because the addressee is *often* "talking rather than doing" doesn't make that an inherent part of the meaning. Which meaning *always* involves "addressee failing to perform some specific action" - but I should have also said that there's nearly always a strong implication that addressee's *current* "status / activity" is preventing anyone *else* from performing that action instead.

Comment: Google "shit or get off the pot" and you'll find a variety of other meanings, like "make a decision already" or "stop wasting time and do it". But none of them correspond with "shape up or ship out".